# How to prevent ViewModel from getting killed when navigating in Android using Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-activity, navigation

Consider this:

We have: MainActivity, FragmentA, FragmentAViewModel, FragmentB, FragmentC

MainActivity is being displayed and we are on FragmentA by default. Click a button and navigate to FragmentB. Click a button and navigate to FragmentC.
Now on FragmentC we want to click a button to navigate to FragmentA, but we don't want to have multiple copies of FragmentA in the backstack. So, we want to popup backstack until we reach FragmentA. This is how I do it:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.nav_FragmentA, null, navOptions {
     popUpTo(R.id.nav_FragmentA)
     launchSingleTop = true
})
```

This works as expected, however FragmentAViewModel dies in the process, and when you reach FragmentA, all of the data stored in FragmentAViewModel is lost.

Is there any way to navigate in the manner mentioned above, without having FragmentAViewModel destroyed?

Comment: Which object is FragmentAViewModel scoped to? https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-apis

Comment: To the FragmentA of course. val fragmentAViewModel: FragmentAViewModel by viewModels()

Comment: `navigate` is always going to create a new instance of A. If you just want to return to your existing instance, why aren't you using `popBackStack()`?

Comment: Well, that is what I'm currently doing, but it is a manual approach. I was wondering if there is a better way. "popUpTo" is supposed to pop backstack until reaching the target (without poping the target). "launchSingleTop" is supposed to navigate only if you're not already on target. So why doesn't it work as expected? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-to-composable

Comment: Scope the ViewModel to an activity or navGraph: `by activityViewModels()` or `by viewModels({ findNavController().getBackStackEntry(R.id.nav_graph) })
`

Comment: `navigate` is always going to create a new instance of a fragment. `launchSingleTop` with Fragments just means "if there is already an instance of this on the top of the stack, replace it with the new one". Again, why do any of this instead of just using `popBackStack(R.id.nav_FragmentA, false)`?

Comment: @Vsevolod Wow! Interesting! This is cool! This solution works! Thank you so much! Does it have any side effects I need to know about?

Comment: ViewModel created with activityViewModels() or navGraphViewModels() is shared between all created FragmentA. If more then one FragmentA is created. Many instances of FragmentA use one instance of FragmentAViewModel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to go back to a Fragment that is already on the [back stack](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-navigate#back-stack), you'll want to use [`navController.popBackStack()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController#popBackStack()):

```
navController.popBackStack(R.id.nav_FragmentA, false)
```

The important thing to realize about `navigate` is that it will always create a new Fragment instance. So what is actually happening is:

1. Before: [`A` -> `B` -> `C`]
2. The `popUpTo` happens first, leaving you with [`A`]
3. Then the `navigate` with `launchSingleTop` happens, creating a new instance of Fragment A, `A'`. Navigation detects that `A` and `A'` are the same destination, so `launchSingleTop` replaces `A` with `A'`, leaving you with [`A'`].

This differs from `popBackStack`, which simply takes you back to [`A`], which is what you wanted all along.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation of how the "navigate" method works. That was helpful. I am currently using "popBackStack". The thing is that if you want to have that in a complex application, first you need to check if the destination exists in the backstack or not. If it does, use "popBackStack". If it doesn't then navigate normally, and this needs to happen every single time. I was wondering if there is a more straight-forward solution provided natively by Navigation Component. The closest solution is what @Vsevolod mentioned by scoping the fragment viewmodel to nav graph.

Comment: Though I'm not sure if I prefer the manual check and "popBackStack" method or this new solution...

Comment: You don't need to check if it is on the back stack at all - `popBackStack` does nothing if that destination isn't on the back stack and returns false to tell you exactly that.